# Polynomial invariants of infinite reflection groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, geometric-group-theory, invariant-theory, coxeter-groups, reflection-groups

It is a famous theorem of Shepard-Todd that the ring of invariant polynomials of a finite complex reflection group $W$ acting on a complex vector space $V$ is actually itself a polynomial ring. In other words, if $P(V)$ is the polynomial ring on $V$, then $P(V)^W$ is a (finitely generated) polynomial ring.

I would like to know if any work has been done to generalize this to the case of *infinite* complex reflection groups (or perhaps at the very least for complexified (infinite) Coxeter groups). To this end, after reading through modern proofs of the above theorem for finite complex reflection groups, it seems to me like most of the arguments factor through to the infinite case, except perhaps the key fact that the ring of invariant polynomials for a finite linear group is a finitely generated algebra. So, this question more or less boils down to the following:

> If $V$ is a finite dimensional complex vector space, and $W$ is a (not necessarily finite) discrete subgroup of $GL(V)$ which is finitely generated by pseudo-reflections, is the ring of polynomial invariants $P(V)^W$ finitely generated?

Comment: The invariants of $W$ are the same as the invariants of the Zariski closure of $W$. If this closure is reductive, as I think it should be in the Coxeter group case (as it should be an orthogonal group), then this follows from Hilbert's theorem about invariant theory.

Comment: The closure is obviously not reductive, since it is virtually a group of translations (in the cases I can think of). This is virtually unipotent. But maybe it's quite trivial to determine the invariants for the unipotent part, which then boils down to invariants of a finite group.

Comment: @YCor  I think you have just explained why the result fails, cf. Nagata's counterexample to Hilbert's Fourteenth Problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_fourteenth_problem#Nagata's_counterexample

Comment: @JasonStarr did I? for a group of translations the algebra of invariants is obviously finitely generated, so one should certainly have a more complicated unipotent part.

Comment: @YCor  Maybe I am misreading the Wiki page.  Nagata's example does arise from an action of an additive group acting linearly on a vector space.  Perhaps the additive group is not of finite index in a group generated by reflections, maybe that is the issue.

Comment: I see now that in Nagata's example, the fixed linear spaces are not hyperplanes (they are half-dimensional linear spaces).

Comment: @JasonStarr actually I don't really have the right setting in mind, since I thought of affine reflections. So what said on groups of translations is irrelevant. The simplest example I could then think of, arising from the dihedral group, would be generated by the reflections $(x,y)\mapsto (-x,y)$ and $(x,y)\mapsto (-x+y,y)$. The Zariski closure contains, with index two, the group of unipotents $(x,y)\mapsto (x+ty,y)$.

Comment: @YCor I was thinking of the case of hyperbolic Coxeter groups - I forgot the affine case.